# .htaccess : how to bypass all rules when url matches?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_TEST
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/pay|ok|ko|retour/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(blog|www|flashgames).sample.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.sample.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.sample.com/index.php
```

I would like to add that rule at the begib

when url is : http://www.sample.com/test.php then Returns (DO NOTHING), just bypass all rules.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dash `-` as the substitution for [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> **- (dash)**
>      A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path.

With an [`L`|last](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) flag, it will skip all following rules. This means, when you insert a rule at the beginning

```
RewriteRule ^test\.php$ - [L]
```

it will just process `test.php`, as if there were no rules at all.

When you insert this rule somewhere in the middle, Apache will process all rules up to this point and then exit the rule chain.